# Get rid of enter spaces in a sentence

Tags: python

I have a string that looks like this:

```
<type 'str'>
Hi George,

Thanks for sending me your report.

Ill take a look at it and get back to you tomorrow.
```

What I would like to do is to convert this into one string looking like this:

```
Hi George, Thanks for sending me your report. Ill take a look at it and get back to you tomorrow.
```

Any thought on how I can do this?

Comment: `str.replace('\n', '')`

Comment: Use strip -- str.strip()

Comment: @DineshPundkar that won't work. `strip` only removes chars at start & end.

Comment: @AvinashRaj `str.replace('\n', ' ')` since the OP want's a space in between

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this :

```
>>> print(" ".join(input_str.split()))
'Hi George, Thanks for sending me your report. Ill take a look at it and get back to you tomorrow.'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strin  = # Your string
a = strin.replace ('\n',' ')
print (a)
```

result:
`Hi George,  Thanks for sending me your report.  Ill take a look at it and get back to you tomorrow.`

Since you want a space between the sentences, but not an empty line, substitute line breaks With a space.